# Как перевернуть предложение слов?

Tags: javascript

```js
function reverseWords(str) { 
  str.split("").reverse().join("")
} 

// "есть цель достичь путей много всегда" 
reverseWords('всегда много путей достичь цель есть'); 

// "вы должны все их испробовать"
reverseWords('испробовать их все должны вы');
```

Comment: `function reverseWords(str) { return str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ") } console.log(reverseWords('всегда много путей достичь цель есть'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если слова разделены только пробелами, то для решения достаточно заменить разделитель в вызове `split` и `join` на пробел

Также не стоит забывать про `return`, чтобы вернуть значение из функции.

```js
function reverseWords(str) { 
  return str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
} 

// "есть цель достичь путей много всегда" 
console.log(reverseWords('всегда много путей достичь цель есть')); 

// "вы должны все их испробовать"
console.log(reverseWords('испробовать их все должны вы'));
```